# AngularJs - changing from ngRoute to ui-router throwing Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

I changed the routing in my app from ngRoute to ui-router,i am getting two errors:

1. SyntaxError: Unexpected string
2. Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]

config.route.js:

```
(function () {
  var app = angular.module('app');

  //Collect the routes
  app.constant('routes', getRoutes());    

  app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'routes', routeConfigurator]);
  function routeConfigurator('$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', routes) {
    routes.forEach(function (r) {
      $stateProvider.state(r.url, r.config);
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  }

  //Define the routes
  function getRoutes() {
    return [
      {
        url: '/',
        config: {
          templateUrl: 'app/components/dashboard/test/dashboard.html',
          title: 'dashboard',
          settings: {
            nav: 1,
            content: '<i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard'
          }
        }
      }, {
        url: '/admin',
        config: {
          title: 'admin',
          templateUrl: 'app/components/admin/admin.html',
          settings: {
            nav: 2,
            content: '<i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Admin'
          }
        }
      }
    ];
  }
})();
```

Previously it was as follows and working fine:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', 'routes', routeConfigurator]);
  function routeConfigurator($routeProvider, routes) {
    routes.forEach(function (r) {
      $routeProvider.when(r.url, r.config);
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
  }
```

The ui-router module is referenced correctly in app.js, angular-ui-router.min.js file is loading successfully on index.html loading. What am i doing wrong ? Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function routeConfigurator('$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', routes)
```

should be

```
function routeConfigurator($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, routes)
```

That is why you get a `Unexpected string` error.

The second error is a consequence of the first.

Comment: Now its throwing: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProvider%20%3C-%20%24route%20%3C-<div data-ng-include="'/app/common/layouts/left-nav.html'" class="ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">idebar

Comment: That's already another error. Seems you forgot the provider from *ngRoute*, `$routeProvider` in a component.

Comment: So, even though i am using ui-router, i need to reference ngRoute in the app.js and reference angular-route.min.js in Index.html ?

Comment: That's not what I meant. It seems you're trying to inject `$routeProvider` somewhere. You shouldn't have that as you want to remove `ngRoute`.

Comment: Search your `$route*` injections. E.g. `$route`, `$routeParams`, `$routeProvider`.

Comment: There are no $routeProvider injections anywhere, but there are few $route injections. Need to change those to $urlRouterProvider?

Comment: You need to replace them for sure, but with what I can't tell like that. It depends what do you use. Consider opening a new question and post the code there. That would be easier to tell how can you replace them.